# How to Use stankevich-python puppet module?

Tags: python, module, puppet

I am writing a puppet manifest file to install python libraries through pip install.

This python module is installed on the server, link shown below https://forge.puppetlabs.com/stankevich/python

I've installed the module by doing

```
puppet module install stankevich-python
```

Here is the manifest file I created in my sites.pp

```
class { 'python' :
    version           => 'system',
    pip               => 'present'
}
python::pip { 'reportlab' :
    pkgname         => 'reportlab',
    ensure          => latest,
}
```

Errors on my agent state that 'python' resource could not be found

```
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 500 on SERVER: {"message":"Server Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Resource Statement, Could not find declared class python at /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/manifests/site.pp:6:1 on node dev1","issue_kind":"RUNTIME_ERROR","stacktrace":["Warning: The 'stacktrace' property is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of Puppet. For security reasons, stacktraces are not returned with Puppet HTTP Error responses."]}
```

However, I've verified my module is there,

```
$ puppet module list
/home/ubuntu/.puppetlabs/etc/code/modules
├── puppetlabs-stdlib (v4.16.0)
├── stahnma-epel (v1.2.2)
└── stankevich-python (v1.18.2)
```

Any advice appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you saying you installed the module on the client that is subscribed to a master and are running the agent on it to execute puppet?

Answer (score 0):

My bad. I need to run

```
puppet module install stankevich-python
```

in root, which I didn't. After doing that it works.